# Elasticsearch painless count much slower than external program

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I'm trying to count the number of items in a field and save it. With 16 million records, running the following painless query takes 90 minutes:

```
{
  "script": {
    "source": "
       if(ctx._source.myfield.empty) { ctx._source.myfield_count=0 } 
       else { ctx._source.myfield_count=ctx._source.myfield.length }
    ",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```

However, dumping the index to a file, parsing it in python with the same logic, and updating the documents takes only 20 minutes. Is this expected, is my script sub-optimal, or is painless not designed to be performant for these kinds of tasks?

Comment: How big is one document? how big is `myfield`?, in general unless they enormous i'm just guessing your elastic is running on a very weak machine.

Comment: @tomslabbaert the documents are reasonable, `myfield` contains about 10-50 items and there isn't much else in the document. I'm running the es service in a docker container -- is possible that the slowdown is coming from there?

Comment: When you use python do you make partial update or full update?

A good practice with elasticsearch, when all documents need to be updated is to create a new one (with the need field).